# Тип отношений базы данных

Tags: база-данных

Всем привет. Есть база данных,и для неё составил ER-диаграмму. Правильно ли я понимаю,что все связи будут один к одному?

Н-р: у одного пользователя может быть только один статус(или уровень прав),или у одной заявки может быть лишь один жизненный цикл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам таблица "Жизненные циклы" ? она имеет смысл только если один и тот же жизненный цикл может быть у нескольких заявок. Тем более поля в жизненных циклах очень уж смахивают на статус заявки, я бы это по крайней мере так и назвал. Если же эти поля одним статусом не выражаются, то почему бы не держать их непосредственно в заявке ?

Comment: А то, что у одного отдела может быть много пользователей, не в счёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Теоретически" правильно, ситуация когда один статус - один пользователей существовать может, например когда у вас в базе только один пользователь и один статус :). Так же это отношение полезно, если у нас есть БОЛЬШАЯ таблица со многими полями, большинство из которых нам нужно редко, и мы их выносим в отдельную таблицу. Но чаще, на  практике, гораздо полезнее отношение один ко многим, то есть когда одному пользователю соответствует один статус, а одному статусу много пользователей.

Comment: Т.е изменить тип связи у таблицы "Статусы пользователей",а так же у таблицы "Отделы". Я правильно Вас понял?
Изменил начальное изображение

Comment: Или если подумать,то у всех связей,кроме жизненного цикла нужно менять тип связи. Правильно?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT, я не смогу вам подсказать, "как правильно", так как я не знаю вашей задачи, но отношение 1-1 это, обычно, экзотика. И да, еще маленький совет, воспринимайте отношения не как "связь", а как "ограничение" (en. CONSTRAINT) - это спасет вас от многих ошибок.

Comment: ,Я провёл аналогию с пользователями и статусом,и получилось так:
Один пользователь соответствует одному отделу,но одному отделу соответствует много пользователей. Так же к заявкам: одной заявке соответствует один пользователь,но от одного пользователя может быть много заявок. Не смог проследить такую логику для таблицы жизненный цикл: т.е. один жизненный цикл строго соответствует одной заявке,как и у заявки может быть один жизненный цикл. Верная логика?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT, в общем, да